# Vuejs Memory Leaks - runaway vue components?

Tags: firebase, vue.js, memory-leaks, vuex

I have a large vuejs application (vue 2), built using vue CLI, that has recently started to run very slowly and then crash. I've been diligent about using the beforeDestroy() lifecycle hook to delete data. Using the chrome inspection tool, and logging "this" to my console upon destroy(), I'm seeing a ton (over 100) of these VueComponent objects. Is it correct for these to be here? Does anyone know what these are and if it's possible to remove them and save memory?

[image]

Drilling down further, some of these VueComponents have hundreds of children:

[image]

Comment: `this` logged inside a component is the component instance itself.  If you have 100 console logs, then 100 instances of that component are logging themselves before being destroyed.  Whether it's correct or not that so many components are being destroyed at the same time depends _entirely_ on your specific app, which we know nothing about.

Comment: Fair enough... but I'm not loading hundreds and hundreds of components. Any given layout might import 2-3.